# Access mixin properties from controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, mixins

i have a mixin:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    queryParams: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
});
```

and a controller:

```
import SampleMixin from 'app/mixins/sample-mixin';
export Ember.ObjectController.extend(SampleMixin, {
   queryParams: function () {
        var mixinQParams = this.getMixinParams();
        mixinQParams.append('xyz');
        return mixinQParams;
   }.property()
});
```

My questions is how do we get the queryParam of mixins so that we can edit it or add more values i.e. what to use instead of getMixinParams() above inorder to get get mixin properties.

Comment: You may be looking for `concatenatedProperties`.

Comment: but how do i declare a property as concatenatedProperty instead of a regular one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for concatenated properties:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    queryParams: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
    concatenatedProperties: ['queryParams']
});
```

then

```
import SampleMixin from 'app/mixins/sample-mixin';
export Ember.ObjectController.extend(SampleMixin, {
   queryParams: ['xyz']
});
```

now

```
<< this.get('queryParams')
>> ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'xyz']
```

Comment: awesome.
I will test this and get back to you

Comment: @torazaburo can this be used in components too ? I tried it with component it is giving error as `get` is not a function